# Angularjs $http not retrieving data regard url

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel-4

Im really getting tired of not retrieve data in angular with laravel as backend.

Heres my app.js:

```
var lonecesitoApp = angular.module('lonecesitoApp', ['ngRoute']);

lonecesitoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        controller: 'preguntasController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/preguntas.html'
    })
    .when('/pregunta/:id',{
        controller: 'preguntaController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/pregunta.html'
    });
});

lonecesitoApp.factory('Pregunta', function($http){
var preguntas = {};

$http.get('/preguntas').success(function(datos){
    preguntas = datos;
});

return{
    all: function(){
        return preguntas;
    },
    get: function(id){
        var resultado = null;
        angular.forEach(preguntas, function(p){
            if(p.id == id) resultado = p;
        });
        return resultado;
    }
};

});

lonecesitoApp.controller('preguntasController', function($scope, Pregunta){
    $scope.preguntas = Pregunta.all();
});

lonecesitoApp.controller('preguntaController', function($scope, Pregunta, $routeParams){
$scope.pregunta = Pregunta.get($routeParams.id);
});
```

preguntas.html:

```
<ul class="lista-peticion">
    <li ng-repeat="pregunta in preguntas">
        <div class="preguntaItem">
            <h3><a href="#/pregunta/{{pregunta.id}}">{{pregunta.title}}</a></h3>
            <a href="#" class="button radius"> <i class="fi-home"></i></a>
            <p>{{ pregunta.message }}</p>
            <ul class="preguntaItem-tags">
                <li><a href="#">
                        {{ pregunta.user.username }}
                    </a> |
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="secondary label">
                        Creado: {{ pregunta.created_at }}
                    </span>
                    |
                </li>

                <li ng-if="pregunta.deadline == NULL">
                    <span class="success label">No expira</span>
                </li>

                <li ng-if="pregunta.deadline != NULL">
                    <span class="alert label">Expira: {{ pregunta.deadline }}</span>
                </li>

                <li ng-if="pregunta.solved == 1">
                    <i class="fi-check"></i>Resuelta
                </li>

                <li ng-if="pregunta.solved != 1">
                    <i class="fi-x"></i>Resuelta
                </li>

                <li ng-if="pregunta.solved != 1">
                    <a href="#/pregunta/{{pregunta.id}}" class="button radius small">Responder</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

pregunta.html: <--- the detail

```
<div class="preguntaMostrar">

<div class="preguntaMostrarEncabezado">
    <h2> {{pregunta.title}}</h2> 
    <span class="radius secondary label">Creado el {{ pregunta.created_at }} </span>
    <p><a href="#">{{ pregunta.user.username }}</a></p>
</div>

<div class="preguntaMostrarMensaje">
    <p>
        {{ pregunta.message }}
    </p>
</div>

<ul class="preguntaMostrarDetalles">
    <li ng-repeat="tag in pregunta.tags">
        <span class="rounded label">{{ tag.name }}</span>
    </li>
</ul> 

    <div class="preguntaRespuestas">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="respuesta in pregunta.respuesta">

                <div class="respuesta">
                    <p>{{ respuesta.respuesta }}</p>
                    <p>{{ User::find($respuesta->user_id)->username }}</p>
                    <p>
                        ¿Resuelve?<a href="#"><i class="icon-ok-outline"></a></i>
                        Like: <a href="#"><i class="icon-emo-thumbsup"></a></i>
                        No Like: <a href="#"><i class="icon-emo-displeased"></a></i>
                    </p>

                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here some data retrieving by localhost/pregunta/1 <----in laravel, is there a problem withe the # in angular route???

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Solicito albanil para enjarrar casa.",
    "message": "Casa de 10x10 en la colonia centro pago por adelantado.",
    "user_id": "5",
    "image_path": null,
    "created_at": "2014-05-06 02:04:12",
    "updated_at": "2014-05-06 03:12:17",
    "category_id": "1",
    "deadline": "2014-12-12 00:00:00",
    "solved": "1",
    "user": {
        "id": "5",
        "email": "kinopio.00@gmail.com",
        "username": "Luis",
        "password_temp": " ",
        "code": " ",
        "active": "1",
        "created_at": "2014-04-20 22:48:58",
        "updated_at": "2014-05-06 05:14:51"
    },
    "respuesta": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "user_id": "7",
            "question_id": "1",
            "respuesta": "\u00f1lskdjf\u00f1alsdf\u00f1laksdf\u00f1laksd\u00f1flkasflkajsd\u00f1lkfa\u00f1sdf",
            "created_at": "2014-05-24 00:11:24",
            "updated_at": "2014-05-24 00:11:24"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "user_id": "7",
            "question_id": "1",
            "respuesta": "claro que si se puede...",
            "created_at": "2014-05-25 07:56:22",
            "updated_at": "2014-05-25 07:56:23"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "reparaci\u00f3n",
            "description": "Servicio o ayuda para arreglar con lo que tenga que ver tu necesidad. Aplicable a varias categor\u00edas, como Hogar, Transporte, Computaci\u00f3n y Electr\u00f3nica, etc.",
            "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "pivot": {
                "question_id": "1",
                "tag_id": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "dise\u00f1o",
            "description": "Servicios de dise\u00f1o para tu casa u oficina, autom\u00f3vil, fiestas de cumplea\u00f1os, quincea\u00f1os, bodas, etc.",
            "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "pivot": {
                "question_id": "1",
                "tag_id": "3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I don't know what i am missing, but the laravel url '/preguntas' and '/pregunta/1' for example it retrieves me the data... maybe im missing something in the controller, or in the factory.
If i put a simple $http get it works only with all the data, but with a specific id it doesn't, or maybe i just dont know how to do it.
I try to make it simple as possible.
Please help, this is driving me crazy. XD

Comment: Can you post your json object as well, atleast a simple example

Answer (score 0):

I belive your problem is in service

try this:

lonecesitoApp.factory('Pregunta', function ($http, $q) {

```
    var _preguntas = [];
    var _pregunta = {};
```

service = {

```
        preguntas: _preguntas,
        pregunta: _pregunta,
        getall: _getall,
        getbyId: _getbyId
    };

    return service;




    function _getall() {

        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/preguntas').then(

        function (datos) {
            deffered.resolve(datos);
            angular.copy(datos, _preguntas);

        },

        function () {

            deffered.reject()
        }

        );
        return deffered.promise;
    }

    function _getbyId(id) {



        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/preguntas/ + id').then(

        function (datos) {
            deffered.resolve(datos);
            angular.copy(datos[0], _pregunta); // try one of those two
            //angular.copy(datos.data[0], _pregunta);  //<-- just take first object from array
        },

        function () {

            deffered.reject()
        }

        );

        return deffered.promise;

    }


});
```

and preguntasController should be like:

```
lonecesitoApp.controller('preguntasController', function($scope, Pregunta){
    $scope.preguntas = Pregunta.preguntas;
    Pregunta.getall()
});
```

and

```
lonecesitoApp.controller('preguntaController', function($scope, Pregunta, $routeParams){
$scope.pregunta = Pregunta.pregunta;
Pregunta.getbyId($routeParams.id)
});
```

Comment: thanx for the answer sylwester... sadly its retrieving nothing... and there's no error in the console...idk what could it be... :/

Comment: Sorry I've mad mistake var _preguntas = [];
        var _pregunta = {}; definition of those two has to be on begining plese update your code it work for me so it should works for you as well

Comment: OK, it looks like your server returning array with one object when you call '/pregunta/1' we need to update _getbyId(id) function please see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56005/discussion-between-sylwester-and-luisinho-rojas).